# Multicast packet not arrived inside podman correctly. Workaround found, but unclear if it is a firewalld issue or a podman issue?

Tags: java, networking, multicast, firewalld, podman

I am becoming crazy with the firewalld, podman and UDP/Multicast. While I see UDP packets arriving in podman; confirmed using `tcpdump` command. It seems I am unable to configure using a customized firewalld zone with name `knx_multicast` that should accept only when UDP packet is from multicast group `224.0.23.12:3671`.

Given minimal example, written in Java:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        final var group = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.23.12");
        final var s = new MulticastSocket(3671);

        final var ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("enp1s0");
        s.setNetworkInterface(ni);
        s.joinGroup(group);

        System.out.println("Start listening ... @" + ni );

        final var buf = new byte[1000];
        DatagramPacket recv = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        s.receive(recv);

        System.out.println(recv.getData());

        s.leaveGroup(group);
        s.close();
    }

}
```

I have the firewalld configured as:

```
knx_multicast (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 224.0.23.12
  services: 
  ports: 3671/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp1s0
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

**Testing multicast packet on CentOS 8.1**

Now I tested first in CentOS 8.1 running and it works as the I get some data (see: `[B@61a52fbd` below)

```
[root@PIT-Server ~]# javac Test.java && java Test
Start listening ... @name:enp1s0 (enp1s0)
[B@61a52fbd
```

**Testing multicast packet using PODMAN on CentOS 8.1**

Next step is now to test within a podman container (image: 'adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest' which is running on "Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS") using: `podman run --rm -it --net host docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11 /bin/bash`

Inside the podman I also see the UDP packets arriving from the PIT-KNX (a KNX router).

```
root@PIT-Server:/tcpdump -i enp1s0 udp port 3671
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp1s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:49:35.583901 IP PIT-KNX.pit-router.3671 > 224.0.23.12.3671: UDP, length 17
19:49:36.032139 IP PIT-KNX.pit-router.3671 > 224.0.23.12.3671: UDP, length 18
... lines omitted ...
```

Starting the same java application (which was working outside of container environment) I am unable to get any data (no byte array arrived after "Start listening")

```
root@PIT-Server:/# javac Test.java && java Test
Start listening ... @name:enp1s0 (enp1s0)
```

**Workaround (firewalld)**

After investigating several hours/coffees I figured out that allowing port in the zone=knx_multicast is not enough. I have to add the port to `zone=public` too, using: `firewall-cmd --add-port=3671/udp`. The config of firewalld is now:

```
knx_multicast (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 224.0.23.12
  services: 
  ports: 3671/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp1s0
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 3671/udp    <== ADDED!!!! (that one fixes the problem)
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

**Re-Testing multicast packet using PODMAN on CentOS 8.1**

By re-running the java application I am now able to see the arriving UDP multicast packet (see: `[B@61a52fbd` below)

```
root@PIT-Server:/# javac Test.java && java Test
Start listening ... @name:enp1s0 (enp1s0)
[B@61a52fbd
```

**My questions ... what happened? Next steps?**

Can anyone help me to understand what exactly the issue is? Why do I have to add port to `zone=public` too? Is this a bug or a configuration issue on my side? How can I resolve it without adding the port to the `zone=public`? Do I have a misunderstanding?

I would have been more comfortable by adding a new firewalld zone (called `knx_multicast`) only; and keep the configuration of firewalld `public` zone untouched. Suggestions?

Thank you, Christoph

Comment: Do you realize that multicast group is registered to someone? Using it could cause a conflict. Normally, you want to use a multicast group from the Organization-Local scope (`239.0.0.0/8`).

Comment: "_should accept only when UDP packet is from multicast group `224.0.23.12:3671`._" That should really read that it is to the multicast group, not from the multicast group as multicast groups, like broadcast addresses, are not allowed to be source addresses in IP packets.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it. Yes, 224.0.23.12 is reserved by KNX Assocation (formerly called as EIB) and is used for multicast packets sent by KNX NetIP devices.

D'oh! Looks like you found my issue. I was thinking all the time about packet sent to 224.0.23.12:3671 and I took that as source address *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ron Maupin for pointing the issue. My firewall configuration was wrong.

The issue has been resolved by creating a new service:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-service=knx
firewall-cmd --permanent --service=knx --set-description="KNXnet/IP is a part of KNX standard for transmission of KNX telegrams via Ethernet"
firewall-cmd --permanent --service=knx --set-short=KNX
firewall-cmd --permanent --service=knx --add-port=3671/udp
```

To make able to add the newly created service, reload the firewalld and add it

```
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=knx
```

This will create a service file: `/etc/firewalld/services/knx.xml` with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>KNX</short>
  <description>KNXnet/IP is a part of KNX standard for transmission of KNX telegrams via Ethernet</description>
  <port port="3671" protocol="udp"/>
</service>
```

And the firewall config will look like:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp1s0
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client knx ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```